# Firefox developer tools Inspector advanced preferences

Tags: css, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

The current Firefox version, 122.0, does something new with handling CSS in Developer Tools that I find very annoying. Though it displays the same as before, CSS copies and pastes with the opening bracket on a new line. So CSS that looks like this:

```
#categories_wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  width: 535px;
}
```

enters my copy buffer and pastes like this:

```
#categories_wrapper
{
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  width: 535px;
}
```

This is obviously not life or death, but I prefer the former formatting and am wasting time changing it each time I paste CSS from the Dev Tools Inspector window to my code editor. I've viewed the existing Developer Tools preferences and find nothing that addresses this concern.

Is there any way that I can change this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that this happens with other apps than your code editor?